# In order traversal for this BTree implementation?

Tags: scala, b-tree, inorder

New learner in scala. I have these base classes for all Nodes and BTree

```
abstract sealed class Node[T](implicit val ord : Ordering[T])

abstract sealed class BTree[T](implicit ord : Ordering[T])
extends Node[T] {
def size : Int
def depth : Int
```

And heres the base case clases

```
object BTree {
//empty node
final case class EmptyNode[T]()(implicit ord : Ordering[T])
  extends BTree[T] {
val size : Int = 0
val depth : Int = 0
}
//node with 1 child
final case class OneNode[T](t : BTree[T])(implicit ord : Ordering[T])
  extends Node[T] {
val size : Int = t.size
val depth : Int = t.depth + 1
}
//node with 2 children
final case class TwoNode[T](t1 : BTree[T], u1 : T, t2 : BTree[T])
                      (implicit ord : Ordering[T]) extends BTree[T] {
val size : Int = t1.size + t2.size + 1
val depth : Int = max(t1.depth, t2.depth) + 1
}
```

And they continue the pattern for `ThreeNode` and `FourNode`

Now in the `BTree` class, I have to implement an In Order function, which returns a list of the entries sorted.

```
// Return List of values sorted alphabetically/smallest to largest
def inOrder() : List[T] =
```

Can anyone help in how to implement this? Im thinking inside the `inOrder` function, I have another function that is recursively called. But I dont know what to do with the List. Do I append to it before every recursive call?

Any help appreciated

Comment: You still haven't fixed `OneNode` from your previous question. It needs to inherit from `BTree` not `Node`, and it needs to have a value member `u1` to be consistent with `TwoNode`.

Comment: I don't see how a `OneNode` element could exist in a proper [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). A single child node can't represent both less-than and greater-then the node key (data) value, and if there is no key then it should be an `EmptyNode` with no need for a child node.

Comment: @Tim its for an assignment, and its the skeleton we were given. I do not think we are allowed to alter it

Comment: @jwvh Yeah it does not exist in a proper BTree. However its use comes in when doing deletions and such

Answer (score 1):

Trying to sort the values as you read them from an unsorted tree is going to be unnecessarily complicated.

So you have two options:

1) Read all the values from the tree into a `List` and then sort the `List`

2) Keep the tree sorted as you build it so that for each node, all the values in the `left` branch are `<` the node value and all the values in the `right` branch are `>=` the node value. You can then get a sorted list by traversing the tree left-to-right in depth-first order. In this case you would never use `ThreeNode` or `FourNode` which (as I pointed out in a earlier answer) make things much more complicated.

This is the classic way to sort data using a Binary Tree.

Comment: Yes a BTree is self balancing, right? So a In Order Depth First traversal would be the way to go. Im just having trouble with the logic of how it would work, in regards to both the algorithm and Scala.

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe A binary tree is not self-balancing, it is just a tree structure with at most two branches at each node. A binary tree used for sorting can be self-balancing or not depending on the implementation. Your `BTree` is not a binary tree if it has `ThreeNode` or `FourNode` elements.

Comment: sorry, I meant a `B-Tree`

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the intent of your structures. 
I would expect a B-Tree node to look something like this:

```
case class Node[T](smaller: Seq[Node[T]] = Nil, data: Seq[([T], Seq[Node[T]])] = Nil) {
  def inOrder: Seq[T] = smaller.flatMap(_.inOrder) ++ 
    data.flatMap { case (value, children) => 
      children.flatMap(_.inOrder) :+ value
    } 
}
```

This assumes that "children" are always "to the right" from the corresponding data (thus the need for `smaller` to keep the subtree that is to the left of everything else in the page.

Comment: It is for an assignment so I cannot change the way structures are made

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe but you _can_ add methods to them, can't you? 
So, just add `val smaller = Seq(t)` to `OneNode`, and `val smaller=t1; val data=Seq(u1 -> Seq(t2))` to `TwoNode` etc. ...

Comment: Im not allowed to do that unfortunately

Comment: Then your question "Now in the BTree class, I have to implement an In Order function" makes no sense ...

Comment: why not? It is in the `abstract sealed class BTree` which extends `Node` and imports the `BTree` object (which I accidentally omitted from my question)

Comment: So, you can add methods to `BTree` but not to `Node`? That seems ... arbitrary ... But still, `def smaller { this match { case o: OneNode => Seq(o.t); case t: TwoNode => Seq(t1) }}` ... etc.